# can't get startDate or endDate to work in my bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a datetimepicker in my project and have looked around and what seems like it should be a very simple solution just seems to not work. I need to make it so you are only able to select the previous 7 days. My code is

```
<div class='input-group date' id='startDateTimeDiv'>       
   <input id="startDateTimeSelection" type='text' class="form-control" name="startDateTimeSelection" style="width: 250px;" /> 
     <span class="input-group-addon"> 
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
     </span>
 </div> 
 <!-- bootstrap date time pickers --> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#startDateTimeDiv').datetimepicker({
          format : 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
          startDate: '-7d'
          widgetPositioning : 
          {
            horizontal : 'right',
            vertical : 'bottom'
           }
        });
    });
```

I've tried using minDate too. I also tried endDate and maxDate and get the same issue. When i try and click the icon to change the date it just doesn't open and nothing happens. Any help appreciated thank you, also, any other ways of being able to select only the previous 7 days would be welcomed.

Comment: Which `datetimepicker` are you using? Have you looked at its documentation? Have you included the relevent files in your html? Have you checked the console for any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the '-7d', so your script is failing.

Also use minDate with moment() to limit to previous 7 days.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#startDateTimeDiv').datetimepicker({
              format : 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
              minDate: moment().subtract(7,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
              widgetPositioning : 
              {
                horizontal : 'right',
                vertical : 'bottom'
               }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much that sorted it. For anyone wondering just do add(1, 'd') instead of the subtract(7, 'd') for max to work. or at least that's what i've got